ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index when converting API JSON response to DataFrame
I'm encountering a ValueError when attempting to convert an API JSON response to a Pandas DataFrame. The error message states: "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index." Below is the relevant part of my code and the traceback. I'm looking for help to understand and resolve this issue as I'm trying to retrieve Tags data through using API:
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import functools
import time

# Define file paths
data_directory = r"\\C:\1. User\1. GD Help Desk"
api_keys_fileName = r'\\C\1. User\1. GD Help Desk\5. LiveAgent_Ziwo_Executable_Api\01-Api_Tokens\Ziwo_liveAgent_ApiKeys.json'

# Load API keys
with open(api_keys_fileName, 'r') as f:
    api_keys = json.loads(f.read())

ApikeyV3 = api_keys['apikeyv3']

# Define hex color map
hex_colour_mapp = {
    "BBBBBB": "Country", "8CC000": "Country", "0098CD": "Channel", "D2DD0E": "Channel",
    "EC3E00": "SLAs", "EF1900": "SLAs", "E10EB4": "PR", "85006C": "PR",
    "21FFDD": "Topic", "3FEB00": "Topic", "3265FF": "Other", "7F009E": "Other",
    "4200C0": "Other", "208E00": "Model", "009C3F": "Internal", "FF7200": "Topic",
    "FF720F": "Topic", "00770A": "Campaign"
}

# Define tag columns
tag_cols = [
    'Answers', 'Notes', 'New answer avg time', 'New answer avg time SLA', 'First assign avg time',
    'First assign avg time SLA', 'First resolve avg time', 'First resolve avg time SLA',
    'Open answer avg time', 'Open answer avg time SLA', 'Created tickets', 'Resolved tickets',
    'Not rated', 'Not rated %', 'Positive ratings', 'Positive ratings %', 'Negative ratings',
    'Negative ratings %', 'Chat messages', 'Chats', 'Missed chats', 'Chat pickup',
    'Chat pickup avg time', 'Chat avg time', 'Incoming messages', 'Incoming chats',
    'Finished chats', 'Unanswered chats'
]

# Timer decorator for measuring function execution time
def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Finished In {round(run_time, 1)} Sec. : {repr(func.__name__)}")
        return value
    return wrapper

# Function to get API data and convert to DataFrame
def get_api_data_to_DataFrame(table_name, _perPage= 0, _from=0, _to= 0):
    '''Converts Api Request To Pandas Dataframe'''
    url = f"https://user.ladesk.com/api/v3/{table_name}?_perPage={_perPage}&_from={_from}&_to={_to}"
    headers = {'apikey' : ApikeyV3,'Timezone-Offset':'14400'}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers)
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json())

# Function to process Tags Table
@timer
def process_Tags_Table():
    df = get_api_data_to_DataFrame('tags')
    df['background_color'] = df['background_color'].astype(str)

    df.insert(3, 'Tag category', df['background_color'])
    df = df.replace({'Tag category': hex_colour_mapp}).drop(columns=['color', 'is_public', 'is_archived'])
    df.columns = ['Id', 'Tag Name', 'Tag category', 'Hex Color']
    df.loc[df['Tag Name'] == 'World Premieres', 'Tag category'] = 'PR'
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=tag_cols)]).fillna(0)
    return df

# Process tags and output the result
tags = process_Tags_Table()
print(tags.head())  # Display the first few rows of the processed tags table

--------------------------------- The error output that I'm getting is below: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 71
     68     return df
     70 # Process tags and output the result
---> 71 tags = process_Tags_Table()
     72 print(tags.head())

Cell In[7], line 42, in timer.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     39 @functools.wraps(func)
     40 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     41     start_time = time.perf_counter()
---> 42     value = func(*args, **kwargs)
     43     end_time = time.perf_counter()
     44     run_time = end_time - start_time

Cell In[7], line 60, in process_Tags_Table()
     58 @timer
     59 def process_Tags_Table():
---> 60     df = get_api_data_to_DataFrame('tags')
     61     df['background_color'] = df['background_color'].astype(str)
     63     df.insert(3, 'Tag category', df['background_color'])

Cell In[7], line 55, in get_api_data_to_DataFrame(table_name, _perPage, _from, _to)
     53 headers = {'apikey' : ApikeyV3,'Timezone-Offset':'14400'}
     54 response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers)
---> 55 return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json())

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1813, in DataFrame.from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1807     raise ValueError(
   1808         f"Expected 'index', 'columns' or 'tight' for orient parameter. "
   1809         f"Got '{orient}' instead"
   1810     )
   1812 if orient != "tight":
-> 1813     return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
   1814 else:
   1815     realdata = data["data"]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:733, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    727     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    728         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    729     )
    731 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    732     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 733     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    734 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    735     from numpy.ma import mrecords

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:503, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    499     else:
    500         # dtype check to exclude e.g. range objects, scalars
    501         arrays = [x.copy() if hasattr(x, "dtype") else x for x in arrays]
--> 503 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:114, in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    111 if verify_integrity:
    112     # figure out the index, if necessary
    113     if index is None:
--> 114         index = _extract_index(arrays)
    115     else:
    116         index = ensure_index(index)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:667, in _extract_index(data)
    664         raise ValueError("Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional")
    666 if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
--> 667     raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
    669 if have_series:
    670     index = union_indexes(indexes)

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

